# As codified the limit of 12 connections appengine to cloudsql

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect my project from app engine with (googleSQL), but I get that error exceeded the maximum of 12 connections in python, I have a CLOUDSQL D8 1000 simultaneous connections

how can i change this number limit conexions, I'm using django and python

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Each single app engine *instance* can have no more than 12 concurrent connections to Cloud SQL -- but then, by default, an instance cannot service more than 8 concurrent requests, unless you have deliberately pushed that up by setting the `max_concurrent_requests` in the `automatic_scaling` stanza to a higher value.

If you've done that, then presumably you're also using a hefty `instance_class` in that module (perhaps the default module), considering also that Django is not the lightest-weight or fastest of web frameworks;  an F4 class, I imagine. Even so, pushing max concurrent requests above 12 may result in latency spikes, especially if serving each and every request also requires other slow, heavy-weight operations such as MySQL ones.

So, consider instead using many more instances, each of a lower (cheaper) class, serving no more than 12 requests each (again, assuming that *every* request you serve will require its own private connection to Cloud SQL -- pooling those up might also be worth considering). For example, an F2 instance costs, per hour, half as much as an F4 one -- it's also about half the power, but, if serving half as many user requests, that should be OK.

I presume, here, that all you're using those connections for is to serve user requests (if not, you could dispatch other, "batch-like" uses to separate modules, perhaps ones with manual or basic scheduling -- but, that's another architectural issue).

Comment: Does this limit also count for Google compute engine instances?